# Web API 2.0 Attribute Routing ("upgraded" from API v1 Code)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm new to c# and asp.net web api.
I'm working with Microsoft Visual Studios 2015 Community Edition.
A few days back i got an old Code. It used the old NuGet-Packages of Microsoft.AspNet.WebAPi(Client/Core/WebHost)(~v4.2).
Then i installed/updated the new Versions (~v5.2.3).
I did that in order to use the Attribute Routing of Web API v2.
I changed some stuff in order to accommodate the version changes.
[How to Upgrade an ASP.NET Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)
I did most of the Steps described in the Link. I didn't do the Steps to change the config Files in the View Folder, because this project doesn't have a View.
The I added 1 simple Methode with Route Attribute and added Route Attribute to an existing Methode

Sample 1:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Hello/world/{num:int}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetSimple(int num)
{
    return Ok(num);
}
```

Sample 2:

```
[HttpGet]
//[AktionName("Confidential Stuff")]
[Route("Hello/world/stuff/{Id:int}/{Id2:int}")]
public HttpResponse Message GetConfidentialStuff(int Id, int Id2)
{
    //do some stuff
    //return stuff
}
```

Build the Project --> Worked ( Warnings about stuff beeing obsolete, but thats a small matter )
Run the Project --> Worked
Used Postman to perfrom the Request. --> partially worked
It did work with calling ' localhost/Hello/world/123 'and returned the 123.
**But**
It didnt work with calling ' localhost/Hello/world/Stuff/1/2. It returned:  HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI (link to adress)

**Edit**

Well now here are some of my questions:
* What is the Problem ?
**My URI i used in Postman was wrong.(misspelled & wrong parameters)**
* How do i fix it?
**Use right URI and parameters**
* Why does Sample 1 work but Sample 2 doesn't?
**Because i was stupid & didn't check**
* If the Code is messed up, why does it compile? Should it not throw an Error?
**Still don't know specific answer, but yes it should throw an Error if code is wrong**
* If there are problems with the code used in Sample 2, should it not still find the adress/resource but then return false Information
**Yes, it should**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the convention routing is not setup to match the routing defined in Sample 2. The default convention routing is only supporting one extra param like `api/{controller}/{id}` which matches Sample 1s method definition.

To solve the problem:

Either you edit the convention in the WebApiConfig.cs class to accept an extra optional routing parameter like this

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{id2}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, id2 = RouteParameter.Optional,  }

);
```

OR, you take advantage of Attribute Routing by defining the props in the querystring instead.

Define the method like this

```
[Route("Hello/world/stuff")]
public HttpResponse Message GetConfidentialStuff(int Id, int Id2)
{
    //do some stuff
    //return stuff
}
```

and call it with `Hello/world/stuff?id=1&id2=2`

Remeber to enable the Attribute Routing in the WebApiConfig.cs class

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Comment: Delted my last comment because i said stupid stuff. Now lets try that again with less stupid wording :) .
I want to take advantage of Attribute Routing but not by defining them in querystring but instead have them be the route like in this Example [Example - Adding Route Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).
In the end i want to have stuff like this localhost/Hello/World/123/Stuff/456/Things

Comment: @IljamoIlias sorry for late replay. I've been investigating the attribute routing constraints but could not found an explanation on why your default constraints options dont work in your setup

Comment: Thank You for your reply and help. The problem was simply stupidity on my part... I should have double and tripple checked what my URI in Postman looked like and spellchecked everything. At least now i know better.